# Angular2 @input pass the array object

Tags: angular

I have two component in my simple Angular todo app

todo-root.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class TodoItem {
  todo: String;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'todo-root',
  template: `
    <div class="todo-root">
      <todo-list [todoList]="todoTaskList"></todo-list>
      <todo-add></todo-add>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TodoRootComponent {
    todoTaskList= [
        {todo: 'todo1'},
        {todo: 'todo2'},
    ]
}
```

todo-list.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class TodoItem {
  todo: String;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'todo-list',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let todoTask of todoList">
        <span>{{todoTask.todo}}</span>
    </div>
  `
})
export class TodoListComponent {

    @Input()
    todoList:TodoItem[] = [];
}
```

how I get the "todoTaskList" values in my "todo-list" component ngFor loop. How to @input work on this type of situation. Can anyone please help.

Comment: it should work just fine, can you create a plunker?

Answer (score -1):

Replace this line

```
@Input() todoList:TodoItem[] = [];
```

with

```
@Input() todoList:TodoItem[];
```

Comment: why? what you define in the constructor has no effect as it will be overridden by input updates